# Pulling property from Redux state returns undefined, although it definitely has a value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been making a small app to learn how to use React and Redux this week, and it's been going quite well but this problem has left me scratching my head.

Here is what my reducers look like.

```
const initialiseState = {
  items: {},
  total: 0
}

function basket(state = initialiseState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_BASKET:
      if(action.sku){
        const quantity = state.items[action.sku] || 0;
        return {
          items: {...state.items, [action.sku]: quantity + 1},
          total:  parseInt(state.total,10) + parseInt(action.price, 10)
        };
      return state
    }

    case REMOVE_FROM_BASKET:
      if(action.sku) {

        // const {[action.sku]: quantity, ...items } = state.items;

        const quantity  = state.items[action.sku];
        const { items } = state;
        if(quantity && quantity > 1) {
          const x = {
            items: {...state, [action.sku]: quantity - 1},
            total: parseInt(state.total,10) - parseInt(action.price, 10)
          };
          console.log(x)
          return;
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      } else {
        return state;
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I have no problems with `ADD_TO_BASKET` however when I try and remove an item from the basket `quantity` is coming back as undefined. I placed a debugger right where the code pulls out that value, and when I run `state.items[action.sku]` in the console it's bringing back the value.

I've just left debugging code in, but you should get the gist of what I'm trying to do.

I'm unsure of what other parts of my code you'd need to see so I can update the question if needs be.

EDIT: Here is the original reducers code before I started debugging, and also the actions file.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  ADD_TO_BASKET,
  REMOVE_FROM_BASKET
} from './actions'

const initialiseState = {
  items: {},
  total: 0
}

function basket(state = initialiseState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_BASKET:
      if(action.sku){
        const quantity = state.items[action.sku] || 0;
        return {
          items: {...state.items, [action.sku]: quantity + 1},
          total:  parseInt(state.total,10) + parseInt(action.price, 10)
        };
      return state
    }

    case REMOVE_FROM_BASKET:
      if(action.sku) {
        const {[action.sku]: quantity, ...items } = state.items;
        if(quantity && quantity > 1) {
          return {
            items: {...state, [action.sku]: quantity - 1},
            total: parseInt(state.total,10) - parseInt(action.price, 10)
          };
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      } else {
        return state;
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const coffeeApp = combineReducers({
  basket,
})

export default coffeeApp
```

actions.js

```
/*
 * action types
 */

export const ADD_TO_BASKET      = 'add to basket'
export const REMOVE_FROM_BASKET = 'remove from basket'
export const ADD_PRODUCTS       = 'add products json to state'

/*
 * action creators
 */

export function addToBasket(sku, price) {
  return { type: ADD_TO_BASKET, sku, price }
}

export function removeFromBasket(sku, price) {
  return { type: REMOVE_FROM_BASKET, sku, price }
}

export function addProducts(products) {
  return { type: ADD_PRODUCTS, payload: products }
}
```

EDIT 2: Fixed misplaced return statement and curly bracket in reducers.

The code is reaching the `REMOVE_FROM_BASKET` statement, as you can see [here at this break point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1QN6.jpg). And the `quantity` variable is undefined. However when in the console I can pull out the value, [here is a screen shot of the console](https://imgur.com/a/U4b1I)

Comment: Below the `console.log(x);` you're not returning `x`, the next state. Is that how you're running it?

Comment: Originally I'm returning the object but I started console logging because it stopped working, then I found out quantity was coming back as undefined so that code block wasn't getting run

Comment: Can you also post the code of action creators?

Comment: @patotoma edited the question for you

Comment: How are you accessing the quantity in your component?

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm not yet as of yet, I hadn't got to coding that part. I had just updated the state to store a quantity and was using the Redux dev tools to check it was working okay.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything right after your `console.log(x)` statement. That's why you are seeing undefined. Try updating that part of code to this:

```
...
if(quantity && quantity > 1) {
  const x = {
    items: {...state, [action.sku]: quantity - 1},
    total: parseInt(state.total,10) - parseInt(action.price, 10)
  };
  console.log(x)
  return x; // <<--- returning new state here!
} else {
  return state;
}
...
```

Comment: I was originally returning the variable but I started debugging to see what was happening by console logging it. Sorry I should update the question to what i originally was returning

Answer (score 0):

Single quote missing in your switch `case`. For more details refer https://github.com/kalaikt/rearch-reactjs/blob/master/src/app/reducers/SearchReducers.jsx

```
const initialiseState = {
  items: {},
  total: 0
}

function basket(state = initialiseState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
      if(action.sku){
        const quantity = state.items[action.sku] || 0;
        return {
          items: {...state.items, [action.sku]: quantity + 1},
          total:  parseInt(state.total,10) + parseInt(action.price, 10)
        };
      return state
    }

    case 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET':
      if(action.sku) {

        // const {[action.sku]: quantity, ...items } = state.items;

        const quantity  = state.items[action.sku];
        const { items } = state;
        if(quantity && quantity > 1) {
          const x = {
            items: {...state, [action.sku]: quantity - 1},
            total: parseInt(state.total,10) - parseInt(action.price, 10)
          };
          console.log(x)
          return;
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      } else {
        return state;
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have set those as constants and imported them, that's why they are capitalised variables.

Comment: Then use like this `import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'` and `case types.ADD_TO_BASKET:`

Comment: The switch case works fine, I've used the same approach with the remove from basket part. So getting into each switch statement isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually with the brackets inside your **basket** reductor function as in reality there is **only one valid case statement** right now.

Let me show you the problem with proper indentation for your current code:

```
function basket(state = initialiseState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // the only valid case statement!
    case ADD_TO_BASKET:
      if(action.sku){
        const quantity = state.items[action.sku] || 0;
        return {
          items: {...state.items, [action.sku]: quantity + 1},
          total:  parseInt(state.total,10) + parseInt(action.price, 10)
        };
        // unreachable code!
        return state
      }
      // case inside case statement here!
      case REMOVE_FROM_BASKET:
        if(action.sku) {
          const {[action.sku]: quantity, ...items } = state.items;
          if(quantity && quantity > 1) {
            return {
              items: {...state, [action.sku]: quantity - 1},
              total: parseInt(state.total,10) - parseInt(action.price, 10)
            };
            return state;
          } else {
            return state;
          }
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      // default inside case statement here!
      default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure you know what to do with that but just to be complete here, you want to use something like this instead:

```
function basket(state = initialiseState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_BASKET:
      if(action.sku) {
        const quantity = state.items[action.sku] || 0;
        return {
          items: {...state.items, [action.sku]: quantity + 1},
          total:  parseInt(state.total,10) + parseInt(action.price, 10)
        };
      } // <<--- proper closing of the if condition here
      return state;

    case REMOVE_FROM_BASKET:
      if(action.sku) {
        const {[action.sku]: quantity, ...items } = state.items;
        if(quantity && quantity > 1) {
          return {
            items: {...state, [action.sku]: quantity - 1},
            total: parseInt(state.total,10) - parseInt(action.price, 10)
          };
        } else {
          return state;
        }
      } else {
        return state;
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also wrap the case blocks with `{ }` to better show the scope

Comment: Sorry, when I rewrote the code I misplaced the return statement. Thanks for pointing that out. However even with that small error it was still reaching the `REMOVE_FROM_BASKET` statement.

Comment: I updated the question with screen shots to show it landing on a breakpoint in the `REMOVE_FROM_BASKET`

Comment: @SkipCloud try changing `const {[action.sku]: quantity, ...items } = state.items;` to `const quantity = state.items[action.sku];`

Comment: I had tried that in the original code I submitted in the question, and it was undefined. I'm quite perplexed by this.

Comment: What does `console.log(state.items);` shows right there?

Comment: There is one object: `{"BA000746": 1}`

Answer (score -1):

I came into work and the senior dev was as confused as I was as to why this wasn't working. I had created the app using `create-react-app`, so I ejected the app so I could see what was happening with the compiled javascript. Lo and behold it just worked after ejecting, I'm not sure what was causing the issue, but ejecting the app fixed it.

If anyone knows why this was happening before then I'd love to know.